# How to write alternaltive pyspark code for the SQL

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
SELECT 
(SELECT DESC_TXT FROM TD WHERE TYP_ID='PN' AND TYP_VAL_ID=A.PN) TP,
(SELECT DESC_TXT FROM TD WHERE TYP_ID='RN' AND TYP_VAL_ID=A.DN1) RN,
(SELECT DESC_TXT FROM TD WHERE TYP_ID='DQN' AND TYP_VAL_ID=A.SN1)AS SN 
FROM TPN;
```

How can i translate the above statement into the pyspark code
1.should I go with joining three time the td Dataframe on individual conditions one by one
2.any alternative approach with UDF.

Comment: did u tried any thing?

Comment: I have tried joining my TPN dataframe with TD dataframe for every condition individually to amend the column but since joining is very costly operation in pyspark i m looking for some alternative solution.